# Getting the total count of column value of a table in html and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I have a table and value is coming from json,I need total number of critical in 'forkscount' column ,here total 11 'critical' is there but how to get that value,I already tried with console and alert but I was not successful,if any one know please need the help,Thanks in Advance.Below is my executed code html,javascript,css,json,this will only can be open in localhost.if you direct want to open by clicking index.html it wont be open.

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="js/script.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4 critical-box" id="critical">critical</div><div id="major" class="col-md-4 major-box">major</div><div id="test" class="col-md-4 All-box">All</div>
</div>
<div id="div">
<div>
 <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="display:none;">test</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>stargazerscount</th>
                <th>forkscount</th>
                <th>description</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>



        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>ssss</div>
</div>
```

### script.js

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/bootstrap-tablefilter/js/members.json", 
        type: "POST",    
        dataType:"json",   
        success: function (response) 
        {
         // var trHTML = '';
          $.each(response, function (key,value) {
             $('table#example TBODY').append('<tr><td style="display:none;">test</td><td>'+value.name+'</td><td>'+value.stargazerscount +'</td><td ><span class="'+ value.forkscount +'">'+value.forkscount +'</span></td><td>'+value.description +'</td></tr>');    
         // var x;
         if(value.forkscount == 'critical'){
             var y=value.forkscount.length;
            console.log(y);
            //  var n = $(y).;

         }

          });

           // $('#table').append(trHTML);
        } 

    });

$(document).ready( function () {

$('#example tbody tr td span.critical').closest('tr').addClass('critialrow');   
$('#example tbody tr td span.major').closest('tr').addClass('majorrow');
 // $('#example').DataTable();
   var tables = $('#example').DataTable({

   dom : '2<"#add">frtip',
    "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "<&nbsp;Previous",
      "next": "next&nbsp;>"
    }
  }

})
$('<label/>').text('Search Column:').appendTo('#add')
$select = $('<select/>').appendTo('#add')

$('<option/>').val('All').text('All').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('0').text('name').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('1').text('stargazerscount').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('2').text('forkscount').appendTo($select);
$('<option/>').val('3').text('description').appendTo($select);
$('input[type="search"]').on( 'keyup change', function () {
  var searchValue = $(this).val();
  var columnSearch = $select.val();

  if(columnSearch == 'All'){
    tables.search(searchValue).draw();
  } else {
    tables.columns(columnSearch).search(searchValue).draw();
  }
 });  

$("div").delegate(".major-box", "click", function(){

    var majorValue = $(this).attr('id');

    if(majorValue== 'major'){
    tables.search(majorValue).draw();
    $("#example_filter input").addClass('white');

  }

});

$(".critical-box").bind("click", function(){

    var criticalssValue = $(this).attr('id');

    if(criticalssValue== 'critical'){
    tables.search(criticalssValue).draw();
  }

});
$("div").delegate(".All-box", "click", function(){

    var criticalssValue = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(criticalssValue);
    if(criticalssValue== 'test'){
    tables.search(criticalssValue).draw();
  }

});
});
```

### members.json

```
[{
            "name": "mango",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "brinjal",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "vagetables"
        },
        {
            "name": "grapes",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "fruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "soap",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "groceries"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        },
        {
            "name": "dates",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "dryfruits"
        },
        {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
         {
            "name": "mobiles",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "major",
            "description": "electronics"
        },
        {
            "name": "shirt",
            "stargazerscount": 526,
            "forkscount": "critical",
            "description": "clothes"
        }


    ]
```

Comment: You should take a look at creating minimal, complete, verified examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  As it is, this is kind of unreadable.  I mean, do we really need your CSS file?  Is every line of code necessary?

Comment: css is not necessary..I have updated the code by removing css and javascript

Answer (score 2):

Create a global var "count" and increase in "each" looping when forkscount is "critical".

```
var count = 0;
...
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/bootstrap-tablefilter/js/members.json", 
    type: "POST",    
    dataType:"json",   
    success: function (response) 
    {         
        $.each(response, function (key,value) {
            ...
            if(value.forkscount == 'critical')
                count++;
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

You can also use promises to get value after "each" conclusion

```
$.each(response, function (key,value) {
    ...
    if(value.forkscount == 'critical')
        count++;
    ...
}).promise().done(function(){ 
    alert("Total 'criticals': " + count); 
});
```